# Haskell: Could not find module ‘Network.HTTP’

Tags: http, haskell, ghc

I am trying to write a simple script that takes as input a URL (or set of URLs) and as output it downloads the contents of that page to a file (in particular I am trying to download hundreds of JSON files, which ultimately I wish to diff against other JSON files).

In a file, `download.hs`, I have `import "HTTP" Network.HTTP`.

When I run: `$ ghc -o download download.hs`

I get the following error:

```
download.hs:24:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Network.HTTP’
    Perhaps you meant Network.TLS (needs flag -package-key tls-1.5.2)
   |
24 | import "HTTP" Network.HTTP
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

My GHC version is:

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.6.5
```

I also get errors like:

```
download.hs:22:1: error:
    Could not load module ‘Control.Concurrent.Async’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘async-2.2.2’.
    You can run ‘:set -package async’ to expose it.
    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)
   |
22 | import "async" Control.Concurrent.Async (mapConcurrently)
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I think it's possible there have been breaking changes between the ghc versions, and the examples I am finding online to start with may be outdated.

Any pointers on doing started with Haskell, and particularly easy ways to download and diff JSON files in Haskell?

I have been following this example: [Running parallel URL downloads in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323265/running-parallel-url-downloads-in-haskell), this is where I got the code that is erroring now.

Comment: You appear to simply be missing the packages that define those modules; they need to be installed.

Comment: You almost certainly don't need the package name in the `import` statement: "You probably don’t need to use this feature, it was added mainly so that we can build backwards-compatible versions of packages when APIs change."

Comment: @chepner Do you mean the "HTTP" isn't necessary in `import "HTTP" Network.HTTP`, that it could just be `import Network.HTTP`?

Also, how do I install these packages? I know you use cabal, but how do you know which package is missing? Should I try `cabal install --lib http`?

Comment: Unless you have `Network.URL` in both the HTTP and url packages, GHC is smart enough to find the correct package.

Comment: I am trying `cabal install --lib network` now ... I removed `"HTTP"` and other package names from the imports.

Comment: @chepner OK, I finished installing `network`, I still get errors like `Could not find module ‘Network.Stream’` and `Could not find module ‘Network.HTTP’`...

Comment: I would use stack. It will save you trouble now and in the future.

Comment: answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67738457/10116440