# Could not find module `Network.HTTP' on simple http get example

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I'm trying this simple example:

```
module Main where
import Network.HTTP

import Lib

get :: String -> IO String
get url = simpleHTTP (getRequest url) >>= getResponseBody

-- 2. Get the response code
getCode :: String -> IO ResponseCode
getCode url = simpleHTTP req >>= getResponseCode
    where req = getRequest url

main :: IO ()
main = do 
    x <- get "http://google.com"
    putStrLn x
```

I get

```
/workspaces/hask_exercises/api-exercises/app/Main.hs:2:1: error:
    Could not find module `Network.HTTP'
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
2 | import Network.HTTP
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I tried from here: [Haskell: Could not find module ‘Network.HTTP’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754127/haskell-could-not-find-module-network-http)

```
cabal install --lib network
cabal: The program 'ghc' version >=7.0.1 is required but it could not be
found.


 ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.10.4
```

Comment: how did you install Haskell (GHC/Cabal)? How did you setup / compile your program?

Comment: which version of cabal are you using?

Comment: @lsmor cabal ` 3.4.0.0`

Comment: @Carsten `sh -c "curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh"` and `stack run`

Comment: My guess is that GHC is not in you path (cabal does not find it) - you write you used `stack` - maybe you did `stack setup`? If it'll not install GHC in your path - and in this case you should use `stack` to install your dependencies too

Comment: @Carsten how should I install? `stack install --lib network` wont work

Comment: @Carsten `stack install network` installed a bunch of things but the error persists

Comment: @Carsten also `ghc` works, it is in PATH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're using `stack` project you should first [add dependency](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#adding-dependencies) in `dependencies` section in your `package.yaml` like that:

```yaml
dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- HTTP
```

and then run `stack build`.